# How to use SearchBar to get data from server

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a design consisting of a TextField, a Button, and a TableView. The user enters a text in the TextField, then clicks the Button which launches a search. When the result returns from the server, the result is shown in the TableView.

Instead of a TextField and a Button, I want to use the SearchBar. I am not clear how to do that. Every tutorial and example I can find talk of UISearchBar **and** UISearchDisplayController, as if the two were inseparable. I only want to use the SearchBar to launch an internet search — with quite truly no connection to the TableView: it’s just incidental that I am displaying the data through a TableView. So how do I make the switch from “TextField and Button” to SearchBar? I imagine all I need is to implement `searchBarSearchButtonClicked`. But is that sound design? I mean, why do people always use UISearchDisplayController? What is UISearchDisplayController anyway? I don’t quite get its value.

Comment: *"What is UISearchDisplayController anyway"* Have you read the docs for `UISearchDisplayController`? Have you looked at sample apps that use it? It's standard. Have you ever searched in the Contacts or Mail apps? That's a `UISearchDisplayController`.

Comment: @rmaddy I read the docs but it's still not clear. It's a problem for me because I especially want to place my SearchBar in my NavigationBar and the easy way to do that seems to be `searchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `UISearchDisplayController` - that is merely a "convenience" construction that combines a tableview with "No Results" message, a search bar and a couple of neat animations. You have two possible choices of how you can make search happen via `UISearchBar` - either send an asynchronous search request every time a new character is inputted into your search bar, while canceling previous search requests to not to receive their callbacks - which is costly from server-side perspective, but pretty neat from usability standpoint or use the approach you've described - perform search upon the `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` event.

Comment: Thanks for replying. +1. But it seems that I need to understand UISearchDisplayController since it's apparently the simplest way to add my SearchBar to my NavigationBar.